# Customize the generated URL with swagger

Tags: spring, proxy, swagger

I'm using swagger to describe my Rest API

So, this is the swaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {


    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .tags(
                        new Tag("Session", "All About Session", 1)
                        )
                .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build();                                           
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("My Rest API")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }
```

My web-service is deployed on this link  `http://localhost:2080/ws1.1/`

Swagger is accessible via `http://localhost:2080/ws1.1/swagger-ui.html`

Now, i setup an Apache server proxy like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName cc.com
      ....
        ProxyPass    /stable  http://localhost:2080/ws1.1/
        ProxyPassReverse /stable  http://localhost:2080/ws1.1/

        <Location "/webapps">
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

with this configuration, swagger-ui is available via `http://cc.com/stable/swagger-ui.html`

Until that, everything is OK

But when i try to run any endpoint of my API, swagger generate a bad URL

this is the generated URL : `http://cc.com/ws1.1/login?login=user&passwd=psw`  -> KO

I expect this URL : `http://cc.com/stable/login?login=user&passwd=psw`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set this property to your `Docket` :

```
@Bean
public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
       .pathMapping("/stable")
```

It will add a servlet path mapping to your endpoint's url.

Comment: hello, thanks for your response, i already test with this, its working, but it must not be hard-coded, i went to have the ProxyPass value what ever was it
 (it work for me like this .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) { Override public String getApplicationBasePath() { return  "stable" } })) but i want samthing like .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) { Override public String getApplicationBasePath() { return  servletContext.getContextPath_of_reverse_proxy(); } })

Comment: As your `Docket`is a bean Spring, you can dynamically set path mapping depending on a property.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this ? i'm not very expert in spring

Comment: you can find plenty of examples for using spring and properties. For example : http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring